# How to highlight status of System Integrity Protection response on mac os x?

Tags: bash

On my laptop, I often run with System Integrity Protection turned off.  I have a geek_script that shows a lot of things I need to know about my settings.  It shows my macs serial number, current version of the os, whether MySQL is running, Latest backup, etc.  I added a line to the script to show the status of System Integrity Protection.  From the command line,

```
csrutil status | grep --color  "disabled"
```

Does exactly what I want producing:

```
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

With the word disabled highlighted in red.

In my geek_script, I preface the script with #!/bin/bash to be sure bash is used to run the script and I have the following line:

```
echo '`csrutil status | grep --color  "disabled"'
```

BUT, the word disabled is not colored.  I've tried using printf, \bin\echo, etc. as various google searches suggested, but to no avail.

1)  How can I get this effect to happen in the geek_script?
2)  Can someone explain why this is happening?  I understand that the command line is executing in bash, but the scripts should be also with the #!/bin/bash at the front, shouldn't they?
3)  If there is a better way, please suggest it.  I have a couple of other places where I want the status of something to be red if 'be aware' and green if this is normal.  E.g. MySQL is running[green], or MySQL is down[red].  This command is:

```
#!/bin/bash
UP=$(pgrep mysqld | wc -l);
if [ $UP != 1 ];
then
   echo "MYSQL is down.";
else
    echo "MySQL is running.";
fi
```

in a file which is sourced from the geek_scripts script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `csrutil status | grep --color  "disabled"`?

Comment: Why are you using `echo` there? Just run the command directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, thank God for these fast processors, I got this to work:

```
 > cat bin/mysql_monitor.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    UP=$(pgrep mysqld | wc -l);
    if [ $UP != 1 ];
    then
       printf "MYSQL is \033[1;31mdown.\033[0m\n";
    else
       printf "MySQL is \033[1;32mrunning.\033[0m\n";
    fi
    #printf "`csrutil status | grep --color 'disabled'`\n";
    if  csrutil status | grep 'disabled' &> /dev/null; then
    printf "System Integrity Protection status: \033[1;31mdisabled\033[0m\n";
    else
    printf "System Integrity Protection status: \033[1;32menabled\033[0m\n";
    fi
```

This produces the MySQL is 'running' ( in green ), or is 'disabled' (in red )
and prints out 'disabled' in red or 'enabled' in green.  The escape codes may be different on different computers, but these worked for me and came from:

```
 https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to prefer the env bash shebang as it does not depend on the bash's path that may vary, but the `/usr/bin/env` command is always there.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

To preserve the color output of the grep command when it is not run in an interactive shell, you use the option `--color=always` See grep manpage

> **--color**[**=***WHEN*], **--colour**[**=***WHEN*]
>   Surround the matched (non-empty) strings, matching lines, context lines, file names, line numbers, byte offsets, and separators (for fields and groups of
>   context lines) with escape sequences to display them in color on the terminal. The colors are defined by the environment variable **GREP_COLORS**. The
>   deprecated environment variable **GREP_COLOR** is still supported, but its setting does not have priority. *WHEN* is **never**, **always**, or
>   **auto**.

```
echo "$(csrutil status | grep --color=always "disabled")"
```

If you want to control the coloring and highlight, use the `tput` command that know the codes to drive your terminal from the `termcap` files, rather than hard-code ANSI escape sequences.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

br="$(tput -S <<<$'setaf 1\nbold\n')" # Bold Red
bg="$(tput -S <<<$'setaf 2\nbold\n')" # Bold Green
ar="$(tput sgr0)" # Text attributes reset

echo "MYSQL is ${br}down${ar}."
echo "MySQL is ${bg}running${ar}."
```